# Login with Facebook not working

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, authentication

I try to login with Facebook from my Wordpress Site, so i am using this code but enable to login. First when we fill login credential then it again return back to same page.

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'MY APP ID', // App ID
        channelUrl : '//SITE URL', // Channel File
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
      });
    };
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
     }(document));
  </script>

  <div class="fb-login-button">Login with Facebook</div>
```

When i create app i just fill my E-mail id, SITE URL and Name of APP. Is there any thing left from my end?

Comment: Its just a sample or your real code? if real the problem is that you didn't provided the appid and channelurl in above code

Comment: it my real code, i know i d'nt write APP ID and CHANNEL URL. Can you please tell me  what s the problem with my code???

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/

Answer (score 0):

if you need to easy way to integrate facebook login on wordpress and more feature there are more free plugins like [facebookall](http://wordpress.org/plugins/facebookall/)